# Theming: when I use a smaller device, my main content goes behind my sidebar

Tags: theming

I am making a sub-theme from the basic theme for Drupal 7. The side bar works fine on all sizes above 480px in length, but on 480px or below, my content goes behind my sidebar and there is a horizontal scrolling bar. I can see the content when I scroll, but I want all the content to fit in the main content area and not in space to the left or extra space to the right. I set my sidebar to the css code of

```
position: fixed;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took out the media selection of 480px for the content, and everything seemed to be working. I narrowed it down to a width: 100%. (inside of the media entry of course) After taking this out, everything was good to go.